# Adjusting elements with css according to the browser size

Tags: html, css

So I have html page like this:
[image]

I'd want to make it so that when I resize my browser or use it on a machine with different resolution the images and buttons would adjust accordingly. I guess their width should be in relationship with the browsers size somehow.

And I also want the buttons to remain in the oder listed above not that they go under each other when I resize (

At the moment the following happens:
[image]

As you might notice the map part adjusts well but I can't figure out why the buttons wont.

Here's my index.html file part:

```
<div class=wrapper">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <a href="" onclick="touch('football')"><img alt="Football"
            src="images/iconsB/football.png" class="toolbarButton" /></a> <a
            href="" onclick="touch('basketball')"><img alt="Basketball"
            src="images/iconsB/basketball.png" class="toolbarButton" /></a> 
            ###and so on until the end of icons###
    </div>
    <div class="loginbar">
        <div>
            <a href="#logged-in-box" class="loggedin_button"
                onclick="touch('addingplaces')">Add places</a>
        </div>
        <div id="loggedinbutton">
            <a href="#login-box" class="login-window"
                onclick="showLoginForm('a.login-window')">Log in</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's my css http://pastebin.com/0DGMfnmh

Any ideas where to start? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why dont u use media Queries ? Do you know it?

Comment: No I'm quite a beginner at web app development. Lookin into media queries right now.

Comment: How about `float: left;` for all the image links. This way they'll wrap automatically when they don't fit a single row anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for **[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)**. With Media Queries you are able to declare CSS rules for specific resolutions only.

If you assign a class to every image, you are able to set the width of the images through media queries. Here is a quick example:

The HTML:

```
<img src='#' class='icon'>
<img src='#' class='icon'>
<img src='#' class='icon'>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Default rule */
.icon {
    width: 64px;
    height: auto;
}

/* Rules for horizontal screen resolution <= 800px */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .icon {
        width: 48px;
    }
}

/* Rules for horizontal screen resolution <= 600px */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .icon {
        width: 32px;
    }
}
```

Comment: When looking at some web page examples that use media queries I think that it is what I need. I have not figured out how to apply it to my project yet but I'll get it eventually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)  it shows you some of the basic with what you can do with media queries if you want them to wrap so going onto separate lines I would follow @Michal 's advice